# A phrase that means “feigning being violated”

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There was a recent phrase I can't remember for **feigning being violated**.

I know the word **perfidy** is sometimes used, but that is not what I am looking for.  I remember seeing something on the media and I just can't remember it.

It's like when someone takes offense for something that was never meant offensively,  making a big to do about nothing. Similar to  positioning oneself to assume the worst in people, never assuming the other person made a genuine mistake.

Think of a person bumping into someone accidentally,  and the other person acts as if they have been physically assaulted.

Comment: Are you talking exclusively about false rape claims or more generally about "being violated"?

Comment: it's like you bump into or brush someone and they act like you violated them.  or sometimes a verbal comment misconstrued or attributed to malice that was never implied.

Comment: *Righteous indignation* or just *indignation*?

Comment: certainly not **righteous** indignation.  might be synonymous with **self-righteous** indignation, but has to have a sense of hyperbole in it.  and it's more than just *"making a mountain out of a molehill"*.

Comment: **sensitive, fragile, prim, moody, touchy, squeamish, prissy, thin-skinned, prudish**

Comment: **Victim playing (also known as playing the victim or self-victimization)**

Comment: Playing the victim card

Comment: i'm wondering if i am conflating with "**victim card**", but i thought it was a new phrase.

Comment: If you would give an example usage, more meaning/context, I could help you get an answer.

Comment: if i could remember the news story.  i thought it might be about race or some victim card playing.  my immediate interest was a FB conversation with a friend where people she might bump (like in the subway) would start screaming at her.  as if she attacked or molested them (but she didn't).

Comment: I've edited your question, and added the example  you mentioned in the comments. If you don't like the changes, you can rollback the edit.

Comment: i'm fine with the edits, @Mari-LouA.  i don't wanna exhibit whatever word it is that i am groping for.

Comment: **Easily offended**? Too conservative?

Comment: "Professional victim", maybe.

Comment: "Faux outrage"?

Answer (score 2):

Is it **feigned outrage?** That has around an order of magnitude more hits than "feigned umbrage" on Google (21K vs. 1.5K) and appears as a phrase used by politicians across the spectrum. For example:

> Yet for all these exacting efforts to do a hard and necessary job and to do it right, we hear from some quarters nothing but **feigned outrage** based on a false narrative. ([Dick Cheney, in an op-ed](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB124295219009745553))

And:

> In an interview with CNN’s Anderson Cooper, President Bill Clinton said there was something “completely disingenuous about the **feigned outrage**” from conservatives over the MoveOn ad. (via [ThinkProgress](http://thinkprogress.org/politics/2007/09/26/16544/clinton-rips-right-wing-for-feigned-outrage-over-moveon-ad/))

Comment: it's more like this **victimization culture**.  feigning victimization to have a pretense of entitlement to respect.

Answer (score 2):

"Feigned Umbrage" sounds sort of clunky and perhaps both words are not commonly used, but I think it perfectly and unambiguously describes the situation, a version of which came to mind yesterday during Michael Cohen's testimony before Congress.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns that might suit your description of a serious and deliberate misreprentation of events:

> [canard](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/canard?s=t)
>   1. a false or baseless, usually derogatory story, report, or rumor.

or

> [calumny](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/calumny?s=t)
>   1. a false and malicious statement designed to injure the reputation of someone or something:
>   *The speech was considered a calumny of the administration.*
>   2. the act of uttering calumnies; slander; defamation.

Other possible words include *fabrication, misrepresentation, distortion, hyperbole, exaggeration, misinterpretation, sensitivity* (in descending order of intent to discredit).

For a phrase, what about "[take umbrage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take-umbrage?s=t)"?

For further directions to pursue, you could start with **[lie](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lie?s=t)** in a thesaurus.

---

LATE EDIT:

**[playing the victim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_playing)** (Wikipedia):

> "Victim playing (also known as playing the
>   victim or self-victimization) is the fabrication of victimhood for a
>   variety of reasons such as to justify abuse of others, to manipulate
>   others, a coping strategy or attention seeking. Where a person is
>   known for regular victim playing, the person may be referred to as a
>   professional victim."

Comment: it wasn't a single word, i don't think.  it was most like *"taking maximum offense"*.  or something akin to hypersensitivity.  i have been trying with online thesauri.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a phrase that might suit.

Comment: we're getting there.  it's **feigning** umbrage.  and there was a phrase i heard in the news, sorta like self-identifying as a victim.

Comment: I know exactly the kind of situation you're describing, but I can't think of a phrase that captures it. I hope someone else can!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Is the sense that the over-reaction is deliberate and knowing or more that they are just hypersensitive.

Comment: the context i was thinking was sorta on the line.  a sense of entitlement to play the victim card when someone harmlessly bumps you or says something to you or some other non-offense.

Answer (score 1):

how about: To cry wolf?

As it relates to the taxi example: "Make a mountain of a molehill" or perhaps more on point: "To lay it on thick".

As for Perfidy, i believe it would be acceptable to use Perfidity.

Comment: it's more like a faux victimization mentality.  just recently i am accused of *"sexist microaggression"* because i used the term *"Sec. Pantsuit"* for the Dem nominee for prez.  (i had also used the term *"Cap'n Combover"* for the GOP nominee.)

Comment: @Stark, as stated with your other answers, please try to give a source for your answer. This site strives to provide objective answers. Find out about good answers in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase that best encapsulates this idea that I can think of would be :

> Affected offense

Used [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jf5KAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA724&lpg=PA724&dq=%22affected+offence%22&source=bl&ots=rglO0ZYVum&sig=-hNyeWqd8I5h0lIkHjQ__WFWU_E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuy-GppZPOAhVQF8AKHTCIBQEQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22affected%20offence%22&f=false) - By John Knox, reference - The Works of John Knox, Volume 6

If you are looking for a noun that comes closest, I would say a [nitpicker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nitpicking) is close, especially in the "pedantic fault-finding" sense of the word.

> Nitpicker

Derived from

> Nitpicking "Fussy or pedantic fault-finding"